# How to achieve swipe functionality that ignores nodata in "top" layer

Tags: dictionary, leaflet, overlay, raster

I want to compare a raster I made against Google's satellite basemap. I produced a georeferenced coloured TIFF with appropriately placed nodata where it should have. I then tiled this using gdal2tiles. When I overlay my custom TIFF on Google sat. map it works fine but my custom map is surrounded by a gray background instead of a transparent one.

[image]

I believe it's because swipe replaces the two layers altogether. Is there a way to achieve what I want properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using [leaflet-side-by-side](https://github.com/digidem/leaflet-side-by-side) plugin?

In that case, and if you need the same background tiles in both sides, a very simple trick is to add that background Tile Layer to the map, but **not** to `L.control.sideBySide`. You can leave the left side as an empty array for example.

```js
var backgroundTiles = L.tileLayer(backgroundTilesUrl).addTo(map);

// Tiles with transparent background
var customTransparentTiles = L.tileLayer(customTilesUrl}).addTo(map);

L.control.sideBySide([], customTransparentTiles).addTo(map);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ve2huzxw/149/

If you need a different background tile layer on the right side (under your custom transparent tiles), simply create a new Tile Layer instance and pass an array of layers as 2nd argument of `L.control.sideBySide`.

Note: for some reason the left Tile Layer must be added last to the map.

```js
var backgroundTilesRight = L.tileLayer(backgroundTilesRightUrl).addTo(map);

var backgroundTilesLeft = L.tileLayer(backgroundTilesLeftUrl).addTo(map);

// Tiles with transparent background
var customTransparentTiles = L.tileLayer(customTilesUrl).addTo(map);

L.control.sideBySide(
  backgroundTilesLeft,
  [
    backgroundTilesRight,
    customTransparentTiles
  ]).addTo(map);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ve2huzxw/150/

Comment: is there a way by which I can load two shape file layers instead of the tile layers using the leaflet-side-by-side plugin? @ghybs